# EntityManager null when implementing UserDetailsService with spring security

Tags: spring-security, nullpointerexception

i am trying to include spring security in a web application. For this i wrote my own UserDetailsService implementation which looks like this:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service("userRepositoryImpl")
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserDetailsService {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager entityManager;

        @Override
        @Transactional(readOnly = true)
        public User loadUserByUsername(String username)
                        throws UsernameNotFoundException {
                User user = entityManager.find(User.class, username);
                if (user == null)
                        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found: "
                                        + username);
                return user;
        }

}
```

My problem is that the entityManager always is null when it calls the loadUserByUserName method. 
I tried some things suggested here in some similar answers, but nothing helped.

This is my current security-app-context.xml:

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/task/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/task/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" /> -->
    <form-login />
</http>

<beans:bean id="userRepositoryImpl" class="de.sveri.jeiwomisa.model.UserRepositoryImpl" autowire="byType">
</beans:bean>        
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
</beans:bean>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userRepositoryImpl">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Any Ideas what might be wrong there?

Regards,
Sven

**Edit:** Trying a bit more i found out that i cannot use the entityManager in my generic DaoImpl during the login process.
**But** i can use it sending and receiving data in another process. This is the Dao:

```
@Transactional
public abstract class DaoImpl<T> implements Dao<T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    public DaoImpl() {
            Type t = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
            ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) t;
            type = (Class) pt.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
...
}
```

I wonder why it is like this. Obviously i dont understand much of how spring works, so it would be great if someone could shed a light.

Comment: Does the injection of the persistence context work in other beans?

Comment: Yes, i use the entityManager in my Generified DaoImpl where i am able to retrieve data from the database via the EM.

Comment: OK. And don't you instanciate your UserRepositoryImpl with "new UserRepositoryImpl()" instead of spring injection?

Comment: I am not sure if i know what you mean? From my understanding spring security instanciates that UserRepositoryImpl when trying to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a nice guy from the spring team in the forums i got it working.
I had to change the xml definition and add a tag so that my security-app-context.xml looks like this:

```
<b:beans xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

....
```

This is the link to the forum entry: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128626-EntityManager-null-when-implementing-UserDetailsService